# rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to build LLB

Tags: docker, dockerfile, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am working on this `docker build` which fails on this line:

```
RUN --mount=type=ssh pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
```

The terminal output shows all the requirements being installed but then I get the following failure:

```
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: 
failed to solve with frontend gateway.v0: 
rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to build LLB: 
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt]: 
runc did not terminate sucessfully
```

I am on Windows 10 + WSL (v1) + Ubuntu 18.04

A colleague runs the same project on Mac OS and does not have any issues...

Any idea what's going wrong? How do I debug it?

Comment: Had this problem too but i think the error message is generic. If it helps anybody, in my case it was because a private git repo that our team was using was down for maintenance and docker couldn't pull from the repo during the build process, which was in the stacktrace.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

After a whole day of struggle, I fixed this by giving Docker more RAM (from 2Gb to 6Gb) and CPU (from 2 to 3)...

Comment: Fixed my same issue. Beyond bizarre that the error thrown gives nothing to that effect.

Comment: I am stuck on this error as well. Tried using your solution but on restart it says there isn't any memory to start Docker Desktop.

Comment: Hello Mehar, that means that you do not have enough memory on your machine... Try to reboot, that often helps, especially on Windows... If not Try 5 or 4 or 3 Gb and see if that helps.

Comment: I also meet this problem, and upgrade my virtual machine memory from 2G to 4G, fix my issue.

Comment: started working for me, after I have cleaned up docker desktop. In a way freeing up all the memory.

Comment: This is a prime example of the usefulness of stackoverflow.

Comment: I observed this issue as well. However, plenty of memory on the box (64 GB) and for docker (about 32 GB), so that couldn't be the issue. In my case I tried to launch a dev container with VS Code. To resolve I waited for a moment, then tried again. The retry was successful.

Answer (score 2):

I had to close and re-open the Docker desktop app to fix the issue!

Answer (score 0):

I use Visual Studio, and when I updated it, I encountered this problem.

This post helped me: [Debugging docker compose. VS can't attach to containers](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/debugging-docker-compose-vs-cant-attach-to-contain/1551330)

It turns out that there is a problem with the latest Visual Studio update and Docker Compose v2. Microsoft is going to release a fix for it soon.

For now, the best thing to do is to disable version 2 of Docker Compose, restart Docker and Visual Studio.

Command to check the current version of Docker Compose: `docker-compose --version`

Command to disable version 2: `docker-compose disable-v2`

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, in my case I try to run the command `docker-compose up` for my nestjs application with the development part of my multi-stage build. So I fixed the error by adding the below line in my docker file :

- `RUN npm install glob rimraf` .
- At the end I have something like this :

```
FROM node:14.0-alpine As development

WORKDIR /usr/src/app    

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install glob rimraf

RUN npm install --only=development

COPY . .

RUN npm run build
```

I hope this answer will be helpfull.